# How did David get the piece of paper saying that his name was "Mike Mckinney"?

Tags: plot-explanation, masterminds

In *Masterminds*, when the hired killer Mike McKinney was about to kill David, He got David's wallet. He got the cash and then found a piece of paper that is somewhat stating that his name was Mike McKinney too.

Where did that paper came from? Or did I miss the scene where he got that?

Answer (score 2):

Steve (Owen Wilson's character) knew Mike McKinney and used his ID to create the fake ID David used to escape with.